# WSO2 API Manager SSL/TLS certificate installation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-gateway

The built-in certificate is causing issues for the API manager to connect to Micro Gateway services when installed on separate server. 
How should custom SSL domain certificate needs to be installed. Does this require creation of new Keystore to store the new domain certificates?

Comment: What are the versions of APIm and MGW you are using. Please check[1] in order to import certificates to toolkit and runtime
[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/MG300/Configuration+for+WSO2+API+Manager+3.0.0